# JQuery web application design patterns

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, web-applications

Are there any design patterns for writing jQuery based ajax-enabled web applications which take care of things like browser back and forward buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is one. Not strictly jQuery related but is applicable.

Comment: PRG only really helps with bookmarking and the browser Refresh, not really so much with Forward and Back buttons. I'd agree it's a good practice though :)